Problem using pyrosm get_data for subregions of Great Britain
For years my code to extract pbf files from Geofabrik using pyrosm for subregions in great-britain has worked. But on 30th October 2024, it suddenly stopped working. It works for cities,
but not counties or other subregions.
The subregions can be named using the following python code
from pyrosm import get_data, sources
print("Sub-regions in Great Britain:", sources.subregions.great_britain.available)
output:
Sub-regions in Great Britain: ['bedfordshire', 'berkshire', 'bristol', 'buckinghamshire', 'cambridgeshire', 'cheshire', 'cornwall', 'cumbria', 'derbyshire', 'devon', 'dorset', 'durham', 'east_sussex', 'east_yorkshire_with_hull', 'england', 'essex', 'gloucestershire', 'greater_london', 'greater_manchester', 'hampshire', 'herefordshire', 'hertfordshire', 'isle_of_wight', 'kent', 'lancashire', 'leicestershire', 'lincolnshire', 'merseyside', 'norfolk', 'north_yorkshire', 'northamptonshire', 'northumberland', 'nottinghamshire', 'oxfordshire', 'rutland', 'scotland', 'shropshire', 'somerset', 'south_yorkshire', 'staffordshire', 'suffolk', 'surrey', 'tyne_and_wear', 'wales', 'warwickshire', 'west_midlands', 'west_sussex', 'west_yorkshire', 'wiltshire', 'worcestershire']
But when I try to get a subregion such as wiltshire:
fp = get_data("wiltshire")
output:
ValueError: PBF-file 'http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain/england/wiltshire-latest.osm.pbf' is temporarily unavailable. Try again later.
It works for cities, such as bristol
fp - get_data("bristol")
output
Downloaded Protobuf data 'Bristol.osm.pbf' (27.92 MB) to:
'/var/folders/0x/731h7wys34z_1cvfpbch5ftw0000gn/T/pyrosm/Bristol.osm.pbf'
